# In Windows 7x64R: set ghost script environment variable

Tags: r, environment-variables, ghostscript

What am I missing here, it works on another PC. From R Im trying to use `Sys.setenv()` to invoke ghost script. Then, normally I can use tools::`find_gs_cmd()` to check that it is set.

Heres the ghostscript exe:

```
> dir("C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.16/bin/")
[1] "gsdll64.dll"  "gsdll64.lib"  "gswin64.exe"  "gswin64c.exe"
```

But when I try to set it I think it does NOT do it:

```
 > Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.16/bin/gswin64c.exe")
 > tools::find_gs_cmd("gswin64c.exe")
 gswin64c.exe 
           ""
```

If I use `Sys.getenv()` it is there on the list of environment variable all right, so Im a little unsure what is happening.
My system is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```